# How to find web element location for dynamic drop down list element?

Tags: java, selenium

I am unable to locate dynamic web element location for drop down list

```
public void selectClassofService(String value) throws InterruptedException
{

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[5]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/input")).click();

   List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[5]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/input"));
    System.out.println("Size of the list size =" + list.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println("names of the divisions " + list.get(i).getText());

        if (list.get(i).getText().contains(value)) {
            list.get(i).click();
            break;
        }

    }
```

this is my sample html code

```
<ui class="vs_dropdown-menu" role="listbox">
<l1 class=vs_dropdown-option role="option">sample pack </l1>
<l2 class=vs_dropdown-option vs vs_dropdown-option--highlight role="option">sample pack </l2>
<l3 class=vs_dropdown-option role="option">sample pack2 </l3>
```

Comment: this is my sample html code 
<ui class="vs_dropdown-menu" role="listbox">
  <l1 class=vs_dropdown-option role="option">sample pack </l1>
  <l2 class=vs_dropdown-option vs vs_dropdown-option--highlight role="option">sample pack </l2>
  <l3 class=vs_dropdown-option role="option">sample pack2 </l3>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, **Stop writing too long xpaths**. there are better ways to access an element instead of doing that creepy things.

```
String dropdownXpath = "//input[@class='vs_dropdown-menu' and @role='listbox']";

new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(dropdownXpath))).click();

List<WebElement> myList = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath(dropdownXpath + "//li[@class='vs_dropdown-option' and @role='option']")));

for (WebElement element:myList)
{
    System.out.println("names of the divisions " + element.getText());
    if(element.getText().contains("Mumbai"));
        element.click();
}
```

if it's not possible to access dropdown like above, just get the parent div's Id like this:

```
String dropdownXpath = "//div[@id='some-id']input[@class='vs_dropdown-menu' and @role='listbox']";
```

**don't waste your time by crawling html tags to find an element.**

Comment: I tried using above solution .but i wont works for me .my intention is to use  desired drop down list element. but this will works for me     driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[5]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/input")).click();
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[5]/div/div[2]/div/ul/li[3]")).click();